# When importing matplotlib. I get the error: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am using matplotlib library in my python project which in turn uses numpy. I have deployed the libraries in AWS Lambda Layers and I am importing them in my AWS lambda function. When I test my AWS Lambda function it throws the following error:

> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed. We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at: numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html Please note and check the following: * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.8" * The NumPy version is: "1.18.5" Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Any idea what could be the possible reason and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering the question so that if anyone in future also faces this issue so the below solution would might work for them as well.

The problem was that I compiled the required packages in windows 10 enviroment and then I deployed them on layers to be used by AWS Lambda function. AWS Lambda function and Layers use Linux in
the background so the packages compiled in the Windows enviroment were not compatible with AWS Lambda function. When I compiled the required packages again in Linux enviroment and deployed them on layers and used them again with lambda function then it worked like a charm!

[This](https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e) Medium article helped me in solving my issue.